# Why are external imports not working for flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am quite confused why imports aren't working when using flask.

## Broken server:

#### *server.py*

```
from service.app import app
# import ssl
from flask import Flask
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print('server is about to start')
  # context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
  # context.load_cert_chain('...')
  app.run()
```

#### *service/app.py*

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

#### *service/routes.py*

```
from service.app import app
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

### Broken server Results:

```
server is about to start
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

When going to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ it pulls a 404. If I put all code into a single file it works as we would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.. turns out that you have to import routes in app.py.

#### Working *service/app.py*

```
import os
from flask import Flask
# from flask_cors import CORS
from blackfynn import Blackfynn
app = Flask(__name__)
# CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
import service.routes as _unused
```

Comment: Close but not quite -- you only have make sure that `service/routes.py` **runs** that is executes `app.route` calls. For example, it's enough to `import service.routes as _unused`

Comment: Thanks @Dima I was curious how to get service.routes to run and this is a good answer. I'll update my solution :)